# how to know sitecore website using which search engine

Tags: sitecore

There are couple of websites in our origination developed in sitecore using a mix of solr and lucene search. Is it possible to figure out which sites use which search engine without looking at the code?

Comment: You mean just from using the site via the front end as a regular user browsing the site?

Comment: yes that is right or maybe do a view source or something?

Comment: No, it's not possible just form the frontend. You would need to look at the code or the configuration.

Comment: Try opening `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` url. Then look for the search configuration

Comment: Sitecore.stackexchange.com is dedicated site for Sitecore related questions, try to use it for any new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, reliably, but you could find out through looking at the source. For instance, if there are instances of Coveo in the source code that's your answer, as Sitecore running it will show this. Further to this if a developer has created a component referencing Lucene or Solr by name, you could confirm it that way. Of course seeing the configs tell you everything but as you said you're trying to find out without gaining admin access.